# My odbc api functions does not get called from ODBC Test

Tags: c++, api, dll, odbc

For the last couple of weeks I been struggling with implementing custom odbc functions.
Here is where I am .
I managed to implement setup functions, and everything works ok. I can create DSN, and it will call my ConfigDSN function and it will register my ODBC in registry under ODBC.INI and it will set driver key and value that is pointing to my customOdbcApi.dll.

Problem is that when I try to connect to my DSN, it does notcall any of the functions,like SQLConnect.

This is response I got when I try to connect to my "AiPandaOdbc"
[image]

But In my function I implemented a message dialog that should pop up and I return 0 from the function not -2[image]

What I checked so far:

Path in registry is correct, it points to the odbcDriver.dll

I added .def file in which I added all of the functions that I want to export.

[image]

Only thing that is very interesting is that If I put MessageBox call in DllMain, then messsage box shows, so my dll is 100% recongnized.

What Am I missing or forgoting to add so that my functions get called ?

EDIT:
I also tried with console application but still nothing, SQLAllocHandle returns 0 but SQLConnect returns -1[image]

EDIT 2:

I added the #undef UNICODE, so I make sure that he calls SQLConnect instead of SQLConnectW. But problems still remains. Still my SQLConnect doesnt get called.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```html
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>
        <h1>ODBC TRACE LOG</h1>

        <textarea style="width:90%;height:900px;">
            
ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 ENTER SQLAllocHandle 
SQLSMALLINT                  1 <SQL_HANDLE_ENV>
SQLHANDLE           0x00000000
SQLHANDLE *         0x00A5C138

ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 EXIT  SQLAllocHandle  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
SQLSMALLINT                  1 <SQL_HANDLE_ENV>
SQLHANDLE           0x00000000
SQLHANDLE *         0x00A5C138 ( 0x00DD7938)

ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 ENTER SQLSetEnvAttr 
SQLHENV             0x00DD7938
SQLINTEGER                 200 <SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION>
SQLPOINTER                 3 <SQL_OV_ODBC3>
SQLINTEGER                   0 

ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 EXIT  SQLSetEnvAttr  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
SQLHENV             0x00DD7938
SQLINTEGER                 200 <SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION>
SQLPOINTER                 3 <SQL_OV_ODBC3>
SQLINTEGER                   0 

ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 ENTER SQLAllocHandle 
SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
SQLHANDLE           0x00DD7938
SQLHANDLE *         0x00A5C13C

ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 EXIT  SQLAllocHandle  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
SQLHANDLE           0x00DD7938
SQLHANDLE *         0x00A5C13C ( 0x00DD79B8)

ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 ENTER SQLConnectW 
HDBC                0x00DD79B8
WCHAR *             0x00DD04D0 [      -3] "AiPandaODBC\ 0"
SWORD                       -3 
WCHAR *             0x73382440 [      -3] "******\ 0"
SWORD                       -3 
WCHAR *             0x73382440 [      -3] "******\ 0"
SWORD                       -3 

ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 EXIT  SQLConnectW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
HDBC                0x00DD79B8
WCHAR *             0x00DD04D0 [      -3] "AiPandaODBC\ 0"
SWORD                       -3 
WCHAR *             0x73382440 [      -3] "******\ 0"
SWORD                       -3 
WCHAR *             0x73382440 [      -3] "******\ 0"
SWORD                       -3 

DIAG [IM001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function (0) 

ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 ENTER SQLFreeHandle 
SQLSMALLINT                  1 <SQL_HANDLE_ENV>
SQLHANDLE           0x00A5C138

ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 EXIT  SQLFreeHandle  with return code -2 (SQL_INVALID_HANDLE)
SQLSMALLINT                  1 <SQL_HANDLE_ENV>
SQLHANDLE           0x00A5C138

ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 ENTER SQLFreeHandle 
SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
SQLHANDLE           0x00A5C13C

ConsoleApplicat 3120-6500 EXIT  SQLFreeHandle  with return code -2 (SQL_INVALID_HANDLE)
SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
SQLHANDLE           0x00A5C13C

        </textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason he keeps calling SQLConnectW even though I have put #undef UNICODE

EDIT - I tried with adding the SQLConnectW function and exporting it, but still nothing.

[image]

Comment: I think odbc driver manager doesn't call your function because you don't call SQLAllocHandle prior to connect call. Once ConnectionHandle parameter is SQL_NULL_HDBC it's no use in calling connection function and it just returns "invalid handle" error.

Comment: I also made console application where I call SQLAllocHandle before I call SQLConnect and still it doesn't work

Comment: Is your implementation of SQLAllocHandle called when you run the test console app? Does SQLAllocHandle call report any error?

Comment: Yes, and it returns SQL_SUCCESS

Comment: So it displays message box twice and fails with -1 error code? It's strange then... Try to get extended error code, SQLSTATE, maybe it will help to understand what is wrong here.

Comment: Yeah,but message box is from DllMain function not SQLConnect, it is like he doesnt call my SQLConnect, but from someone else, because if he called my SQLConnect there should be another message box.

Comment: Question, I dont understand the SQLConnectW,SQLConnectA, I saw that one is for ansi another for unicode. Do I maybe need to change my driver implementation because of that or something ?

Comment: Yes, it seems you're correct. I didn't notice that your test client application was Unicode. So try also to implement SQLConnectW and SQLDriverConnectW (with SQLWCHAR string arguments). Btw it's not correct just converting (const char *) to (SQLWCHAR *) like you do in your test app: char != SQLWCHAR. You should declare all your string constants using wide char type to specify them as Unicode function arguments.

Comment: Try to turn on ODBC tracing ("Tracing" tab of ODBC Data Source Administrator), then run your test application, then turn the tracing off and attach the log here.

Comment: I edit the question and attach the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either call SQLConnectW and pass actual SQLWCHAR DSN string, or Call SQLConnectA to explicitly call the ANSI function, or undefine UNICODE when building code (add #undef UNICODE to top of source) to prevent the call to SQLConnect from being quietly mapped to SQLConnectW.

I am guessing you added the cast to SQLWCHAR* to prevent the compiler from complaining which is the clue that SQLConnect is not being called.

Comment: I tried with #undef UNICODE, I added new pictures on my question on the top. Problem still remains, it just calls DllMain Function and that is all.

Comment: The DriverManager is reporting "function not found", it may be looking for SQLGetFunctions. I find its best to start with stubs for ALL the odbs functions A and W with debug to show you which is being called. But the odbc trace shows your DSN getting through ok, so I think UNICODE (or the absense of it) is doing its job.

Comment: I tried with debug, but he only gets inside DllMain function and I implement the SQLConnectW function

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. I implemented all functions and it worked